# Kohana Session Table

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

Currently i am hosting a website with ~10k unique visitors a day and ~6 clicks per user.

So round about 60k pageviews a day.

I use Kohana 3.2 and save the session datas from every user in the "sessions" table. Every page request execute a timestamp refresh in this table! So it's round about 60k updates (excl. Selects / Inserts / .. ) refreshing timestamps only.

The mysql process is getting pretty low..

So that's my question:

- Should i stop using the `SESSIONS` table for saving user
- How can i use the `$_SESSION` instead the values from the table?
- Is there another alternative to handle this problem right now? We orderd more server capacity but have to wait..

EDIT:
Maybe it's enough to deny all these "updates" by every click..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. At least it was enough to truncate the table "sessions" - for the first moment. There was more than 1kk records - thats why the database operations getting pretty slow..?

Maybe it's just a simple mysql problem, and it's enough when i change it NOSQL.